# Show account's first name in SharePoint through Masterpage

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, master-pages

All the account details are in Active Directory and SP is connected to it.  I'm trying to pull in the first name and display it on a page through Masterpage.  I'm new to asp.net so I don't know how to go about doing this.  Is it as simple as adding a string in the Masterpage to pull in that info? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Christian](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/5d4277fe-40d1-449b-a79a-421fddee9bd9) on MSDN forum.

Register SPSWC at the top of the masterpage:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Register the propertys below the starting Form tag:

```
<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyLoader runat="server"/>
```

Place this Property somewhere in the master pages markup:

```
<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="FirstName" ApplyFormatting="false" runat="server"/>
```